# how can i get value of dynamic element with on click in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
// I want to get data of clicked class which is $('.add_another_ele')

$('#table-body').on('click',$('.add_other_ele'),function(){
  //get id of $(.add_other_ele)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.add_other_ele' ,function()...`

Comment: also if you want the value use `$(this).val()` inside the click function

Comment: Please provide simple HTML code.

Comment: its Done....I user $(document).on('click', '.add_other_ele', function(){})